# Menu slider using css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
 $(".menu-item-5").hover(function() {
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('zero');
   });
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($("#menu-item-5").hasClass("current")) {
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('zero');
     }
   });

   // MENU ITEM
   $(".menu-item-6").hover(function() {
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('twenty_five');
   });
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($("#menu-item-6").hasClass("current")) {
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('twenty_five');
     }
   });

   // MENU ITEM
   $(".menu-item-7").hover(function() {
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('fifty');
   });
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($("#menu-item-7").hasClass("current")) {
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('fifty');
     }
   });

   // MENU ITEM
   $(".menu-item-8").hover(function() {
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('seventy_five');
   });
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($("#menu-item-8").hasClass("current")) {
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('seventy_five');
     }
   });
```

```css
html, body, .wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #b61924;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#rcolumn {
  background-color: #b61924;
  width: 45%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}

#lcolumn {
  background-color: #b61924;
  width: 55%;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
}

.nav {
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 44px 0;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
hr {
  height: 1px;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f99d33;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  text-align: left;
}
hr.zero {
  left: 0;
}
hr.twenty_five {
  left: 25%;
}
hr.fifty {
  left: 50%;
}
hr.seventy_five {
  left: 75%;
}

#lcolumn {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(images/skyline.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.logowrap {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -150px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: opacity .5s ease 1.25s;
}

.logowrap h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.8em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="column" id="lcolumn">
        <nav role="navigation" class="desktop cf">
          <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav top-nav cf">
            <li id="menu-item-5">
              <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-6">
              <a href="#">cookies</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-7">
              <a href="#">icecream</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-8">
              <a href="#">chocolate</a>
            </li>
            <hr>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="rcontent">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id="rcolumn">
        <div class="logo" style="height: 100%;">
       
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Hi I am trying to get the element HR to slide across horizontally depending on which menu item is hovered or clicked. It working in chrome but not in IE/Firefox. When I get it to work in IE/Firefox by fiddling with the css code it stops working on Chrome. A simple solution is needed.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".menu-item-5").hover(function() {
    $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
    $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('zero');
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($("#menu-item-5").hasClass("current")) {
      $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
      $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('zero');
    }
  });

  // MENU ITEM
  $(".menu-item-6").hover(function() {
    $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
    $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('twenty_five');
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($("#menu-item-6").hasClass("current")) {
      $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
      $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('twenty_five');
    }
  });

  // MENU ITEM
  $(".menu-item-7").hover(function() {
    $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
    $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('fifty');
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($("#menu-item-7").hasClass("current")) {
      $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
      $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('fifty');
    }
  });

  // MENU ITEM
  $(".menu-item-8").hover(function() {
    $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
    $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('seventy_five');
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($("#menu-item-8").hasClass("current")) {
      $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
      $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('seventy_five');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.nav {
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 44px 0;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
hr {
  height: 1px;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f99d33;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  text-align: left;
}
hr.zero {
  left: 0;
}
hr.twenty_five {
  left: 25%;
}
hr.fifty {
  left: 50%;
}
hr.seventy_five {
  left: 75%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav role="navigation" class="desktop cf">
  <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav top-nav cf">
    <li id="menu-item-5">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-6">
      <a href="#">cookies</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-7">
      <a href="#">icecream</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-8">
      <a href="#">chocolate</a>
    </li>
    <hr>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I see a lot of duplicated code. Please use a function or write a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your elements have IDs but your JavaScript is calling them by a class identifier. Change either your elements to have a class attribute or change the JavaScript to call them by id.

I did the former below:

***Edit:** I converted your main logic into a jQuery plugin. It is easy to follow.*

See the changes I made to your percentage class names. Proper CSS naming conventions use dashes (-) to separate words in IDs and class names.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.onHoverSlide = function(sliderSelector, className) {
    var $this = this;
    var $slider = $(sliderSelector); // The slider object (<hr/>).
    $this.hover(function() {
      $slider.attr('class', '');   // Clear all classes.
      $slider.addClass(className); // Add current hover class.
    });
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($this.hasClass('current')) {
        $this.trigger('hover'); // Reuse hover logic defined above.
      }
    });
    return $this; // Return self for chaining.
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function($) {
  var sliderSelector = '#menu-main-menu hr';
  $('.menu-item-5').onHoverSlide(sliderSelector, 'zero');
  $('.menu-item-6').onHoverSlide(sliderSelector, 'twenty-five');
  $('.menu-item-7').onHoverSlide(sliderSelector, 'fifty');
  $('.menu-item-8').onHoverSlide(sliderSelector, 'seventy-five');
});
```

```css
.nav {
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 44px 0;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
          transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
hr {
  height: 1px;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f99d33;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
          transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-align: left;
}
hr.zero         { left:  0;  }
hr.twenty-five  { left: 25%; }
hr.fifty        { left: 50%; }
hr.seventy-five { left: 75%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav role="navigation" class="desktop cf">
  <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav top-nav cf">
    <li class="menu-item-5">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-6">
      <a href="#">cookies</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-7">
      <a href="#">icecream</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-8">
      <a href="#">chocolate</a>
    </li>
    <hr>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I was working with identifiers before I tried to switch to class, I guess I mixed up the code it copied and pasted here. However It works either way, but the problem is that it works fine on chrome but when I open it on firefox or IE it stops working. When I get it to work on firefox/IE it stops working in chrome. I dont know if am missing some -webkit kind of code in the css

Comment: Which version of Chrome? It is working on the latest version.

Comment: Your `.nav li a` css class defines the Firefox and Chome `transition` rules, but not the regular `transition`, BUT your `hr` is the complete opposite. Make sure you add the -webkit-, -moz-, and plain CSS3 rules to each classes rulesets.

Comment: @Joseph Did you forget to scroll down and see my response? You just kinda ignored my feedback.

Comment: I was checking out the other solutions. Just used your solution its working on IE/Firefox but not on Chrome. I had to change hr.zero {left:  0;  } to hr.zero { margin-left:  0;  } before I could get it working on chromo. For some reason its only margin-left that works. Thanks for your jquery code, its the proper way to do things. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use the correct selectors,

in your html you have

```
 <li id="menu-item-5">
```

but in your script

you are using

```
$(".menu-item-5").hover(function() {
```

you have id in your html and on hover function you are using it as a class selector.

you may use

```
 $("#menu-item-5").hover(function() {
```

P.S: I have tested this in chrome, firefox and IE 11 and it works fine.

```js
$("#menu-item-5").hover(function() {
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('zero');
   });
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($("#menu-item-5").hasClass("current")) {
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('zero');
     }
   });

   // MENU ITEM
   $("#menu-item-6").hover(function() {
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('twenty_five');
   });
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($("#menu-item-6").hasClass("current")) {
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('twenty_five');
     }
   });

   // MENU ITEM
   $("#menu-item-7").hover(function() {
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('fifty');
   });
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($("#menu-item-7").hasClass("current")) {
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('fifty');
     }
   });

   // MENU ITEM
   $("#menu-item-8").hover(function() {
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
     $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('seventy_five');
   });
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     if ($("#menu-item-8").hasClass("current")) {
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").attr("class", "");
       $("#menu-main-menu hr").addClass('seventy_five');
     }
   });
```

```css
html, body, .wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #b61924;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#rcolumn {
  background-color: #b61924;
  width: 45%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}

#lcolumn {
  background-color: #b61924;
  width: 55%;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
}

.nav {
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 44px 0;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
hr {
  height: 1px;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f99d33;
  border: none;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  text-align: left;
}
hr.zero {
  left: 0;
}
hr.twenty_five {
  left: 25%;
}
hr.fifty {
  left: 50%;
}
hr.seventy_five {
  left: 75%;
}

#lcolumn {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(images/skyline.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.logowrap {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: auto;
  width: 300px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -150px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: opacity .5s ease 1.25s;
}

.logowrap h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.8em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="column" id="lcolumn">
        <nav role="navigation" class="desktop cf">
          <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav top-nav cf">
            <li id="menu-item-5">
              <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-6">
              <a href="#">cookies</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-7">
              <a href="#">icecream</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-8">
              <a href="#">chocolate</a>
            </li>
            <hr>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="rcontent">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column" id="rcolumn">
        <div class="logo" style="height: 100%;">
       
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks. I think I should paste my full html structure so that you understand my problem

Comment: @Joseph you can provide fiddle/plunker with your complete code

Comment: @Joseph in this snippet also same selector issue was there, and after correcting it , it works on all IE11, chrome, firefox

Comment: Okay thanks for your comments it was very helpful. Am a bit worked up over this issue thats why am pasting wrong selectors. I need to relax and take my mind off this for a few hours

Comment: @Joseph NP :) glad to help, it does happen some time with everyone